# How to best merge two dataframes based on data range?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes. On has a date range column with an event, the other one a column with a value. I would like to add the event to the measured value and the respective date.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["timestamp", "measured value"],
    data=[
        (pd.to_datetime("2012-07-16 23:23:50"), 2.1),
        (pd.to_datetime("2012-08-16 02:23:50"), 4),
        (pd.to_datetime("2015-07-16 12:23:50"), 2),
        (pd.to_datetime("2018-08-16 20:23:50"), 1.2),
    ],
)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["start", "end", "event"],
    data=[
        
        (
            pd.to_datetime("2015-06-16 12:23:50"),
            pd.to_datetime("2015-08-16 12:23:50"),
            True,
        ),
       
    ],
)
```

I tried the following:

```
df_2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2["start"], df_2["end"], closed="both")
df_1.assign(events = df_2['event'])

 timestamp  measured value events
0 2012-07-16 23:23:50    2.1    NaN
1 2012-08-16 02:23:50    4.0    NaN
2 2015-07-16 12:23:50    2.0    NaN
3 2018-08-16 20:23:50    1.2    NaN
```

desired output:

```
 timestamp  measured value event
0 2012-07-16 23:23:50    2.1   NaN
1 2012-08-16 02:23:50    4.0   NaN
2 2015-07-16 12:23:50    2.0  True
3 2018-08-16 20:23:50    1.2   NaN
```

Comment: I assume the date range has no overlaps?

Comment: Yes, here there are no overlaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not so far, use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and convert to numpy array:

```
df_2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_2["start"], df_2["end"], closed="both")

df_1['event'] = df_2['event'].reindex(df_1['timestamp']).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
            timestamp  measured value event
0 2012-07-16 23:23:50             2.1   NaN
1 2012-08-16 02:23:50             4.0   NaN
2 2015-07-16 12:23:50             2.0  True
3 2018-08-16 20:23:50             1.2   NaN
```

Or, make "timestamp" the index of `df_1`:

```
df_1.set_index('timestamp').assign(event=df_2['event'])
```

Output:

```
                     measured value event
timestamp                                
2012-07-16 23:23:50             2.1   NaN
2012-08-16 02:23:50             4.0   NaN
2015-07-16 12:23:50             2.0  True
2018-08-16 20:23:50             1.2   NaN
```